# Removing spacing between Xamarin.Forms Grid Cells

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am struggling with removing spacing between grid cells. I have tried using ColumnSpacing="0" and RowSpacing = "0",however it does not make grid spaceless.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="XamarinPradmenys.CalculatorPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
            <Label x:Name="live" FontSize="20"/>
            <Label x:Name="rez" FontSize="15"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.75" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="mc" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="m+"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="m-"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="mr"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="C"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="/"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="X"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="Del"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="7"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="8"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="9"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="-"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="5"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="6"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="+"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="1"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="2"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="3"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="="/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Text="%" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Text=","/>
        </Grid>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

That I get is: 
[image: CalcView]
As you can see there are spaces between every row and column. Do you have any suggestions?

Do you have anything what could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because material design, each button has shadows but if you add a background colour, you'll see its true size :

[image]

Code

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#d6d7d7" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <Label x:Name="live" FontSize="20" />
        <Label x:Name="rez" FontSize="15" />
    </StackLayout>

    <Grid
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.75"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="mc" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="m+" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="m-" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="mr" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="C" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="/" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="X" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="Del" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="7" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="8" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="9" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="-" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="4" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="5" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="6" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="+" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="1" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="2" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="3" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="=" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="%" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="0" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="," />
    </Grid>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via custom renderer.

MyButton.cs

```
 public class MyButton : Button
{
}
```

MyButtonRenderer.cs

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
 namespace XamarinDemo.Droid
 {
   public class MyButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
   {

    public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == "BackgroundColor")
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <Label x:Name="live" FontSize="20" />
        <Label x:Name="rez" FontSize="15" />
    </StackLayout>

    <Grid
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.75"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="mc" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="m+" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="m-" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="mr" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="C" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="/" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="X" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="Del" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="7" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="8" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="9" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="-" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="4" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="5" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="6" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="+" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="1" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="2" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="3" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Text="=" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="%" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="0" />
        <local:MyButton
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="," />
    </Grid>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]